# Query to find employee who has worked in all locations

Tags: sql

Imagine a simple employee database:
Employee `[ empId, location vachar (30) ]`

We want to find employee who has worked in all locations ?

Not looking for a specific SQL server.

Comment: i reckon you can imagine for the answer

Comment: imagine first how you define "all locations". Is there another table that contains a list of all locations? If not, you need to get this list of all locations out of this table. How do you think you do that? Use this query to count locations (for example maybe there are 12 locations). You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT Location)` to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for SQL Server (or any database that supports `count(distinct <column>)`:

```
SELECT empId
FROM Employee
GROUP BY empId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT location) FROM Employee)
```